# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint - asp.net.mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im getting that error when im trying to insert data to Tickets Table:

The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Tickets_dbo.Screenings_Date_HallId". The conflict occurred in database "aspnet-CinemaProject-20210105112627", table "dbo.Screenings".
The statement has been terminated.

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public short SeatNumber { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("Date, HallId")]
    public Screening Screening { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }


    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public byte HallId { get; set; }




    public DateTime? CreationTime { get; set; }

    public bool Paid { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
public class Screening
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MovieId")]
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int MovieId { get; set; }
    
    
    [ForeignKey("HallId")]
    public Hall Hall { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Hall")]
    public byte HallId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public short Price { get; set; }

}
```

.

```
public class Hall
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
}
```

can any one help me?

EDIT:

[image: Error]

[image]

(Screening Table)^^

Comment: look like you try insert an invalid date, show us the code of insert ...

Comment: Edited... @B.S.

Comment: You have a very  weird db structure. I've never seen anything like this. You will have problems all the time.

Comment: please take a look to : [Data Annotations - ForeignKey Attribute in EF 6 & EF Core](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) it will be helpful, good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the date you are trying to insert in the "Ticket" table as a foreign key does NOT exist in the "screening" table as a primary key

Comment: Can you provide the solution ?

Comment: The solution is to have select list of those screening dates in the view and select one of them.

Comment: Solved: the date value on Screening table was in different format than on Ticket instance.